# jQuery - pass handler to callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have:

```
run : function(o, path, duration){
    o.handler.animate({path : new $.path.bezier(path)},
        {
            /*step: function(now, fx) {},*/
            duration : duration,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete : function() {
                
            }
        }
    );
    
    return true;
}
```

I want to be able to use `o` inside `complete` callback. Need some guidance.

**Important Note**: without using "global vars". `o` is a reference to `players[11].handler` which references `$('.player[data-id="11"]')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is captured inside a closure you can use it:

```
complete : function() {
    o...
}
```